# Can't access NAS over IPv4 on Windows 11 while other Windows 10 PCs can access it

Tags: windows, networking, ipv6, ipv4, qnap

TL;DR: I can’t access my NAS over IPv4 on my Windows 11 PC while other Windows 10 PCs can access it.

I have an QNAP NAS TS-228 (Firmware 4.3.6) for storing my data. I freshly installed Windows 11 on my PC. Now I can’t access the web interface with the IPv4 address, and I can’t add it as a network drive in Windows Explorer. When I use the IPv6 Address, the web interface opens just fine. I’m also able to ping both IPv4 and IPv6 of the NAS successfully. My IP Address isn’t blocked by the NAS. I also checked the firewall, every file and printer sharing is permitted.

I think I can exclude the NAS as the problem because other Windows 10 devices can access the NAS over IPv4 without any problem. My PC was also able to connect to the NAS after I upgraded it from Windows 10 to 11. However now that I freshly installed Windows 11 the connection isn’t working anymore.

I wasn’t able to use IPv6 in Windows Explorer to add an network drive as explained in this post: https://www.vistax64.com/threads/accessing-computer-shared-folders-using-ipv6.232176/#post1065532 so I would like to use IPv4 for this. Some tutorials suggested to enable SMB 1.0 in Windows features but this doesn’t help either (The Windows 10 devices don’t have it on either).

I have a very simple stock network setup without any further configuration. The NAS has a static IPv4 address. The host name resolution from name to ipv4 works when using ping on the terminal. There is also an answer from the NAS. Connecting to the web interface over QNAPs DDNS and my public IPv4 works, but this doesn't help me connecting it in Windows Explorer as an Network Storage.

**Edit**: For anyone having the same problem: I think it's a Windows 11 Bug. I set my NAS to block every IP address that has 5 or more failed logins. On Windows 10, when you first open the IP in the Explorer, Windows asks for login credentials. This doesn't happen on Windows 11, but the IP gets blocked. I think Windows 11 is sending some login information and doesn't allow to change them.

While Windows Explorer doesn't allow the ipv6 format "*ip-with-minus*.ipv6-literal.net", CMD does. With 
`net use x: \\NAS /user:User Password` it allowed me to add the network drive. It sometimes fails after boot and I get the error that I can't connect twice with the same user, but generally it works.

**Edit2**: Using `net use` without a device letter lets you connect to the IPv4 without any problem. The network drive doesn't show up in the explorer in this case. You can then navigate to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts` and add the shortcut there. The folder is then shown under network.